# Problem adding tow digits to path string to read multiple files

Tags: matlab, printf

I want to read multiple files from a folder, the only problem in my code down is that
instead of having the full image path:

> *'checkboard/Gaussian_Noised/image_01.jpg'*

I have the path without the zero in the last two digits

**EDIT**: There is space instead of zero on the first 9 Image paths.

> *'checkboard/Gaussian_Noised/image_ 1.jpg'*

how can I fix this please

```
%-------------------------------------------------------
clc
clear all
close all
%------------------------------------------------------
path = 'checkboard/Gaussian_Noised/';
% Define images to process
imageFileNames = cell(1,36);
for n = 1:36
imageFileNames{n} = strcat(path,sprintf('image_%2d.jpg',n))
end
%------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @SardarUsama yes you are right

Comment: @SardarUsama I have 36 images: image_01.jpg, image_36.jpg, I need to print 2 digits for the variable `n`

Comment: You have got the answer. Please also note that `path` is a builtin function. Please do not shadow it with your custom variable

Comment: I added a more generic answer in the case that you want to just load files of a certain pattern from a given directory. Than you wouldn't cope with leading zeros or worry if the numbering is not a sequence or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is better to use the float-format-specifier to pad zeros:

```
num2str(1,'%02.f')
```

> '01'

```
num2str(1,'%02.d')
```

> '1'

```
num2str(1,'%2.d')
```

> '1'

```
num2str(1,'%d')
```

> '1'

So in your case:

```
sprintf('image_%02.f.jpg',n)
```

**general advice**
As a general advice, you may want just to check the folder for all files of a certain pattern

```
path2dir = pwd; % path to working directory
pattern = 'image_*.jpg'
Lst = dir(fullfile(path2dir ,pattern));
for i = 1:length(Lst)
    path2file = fullfile(Lst(i).folder,Lst(i).name);
    % load the file and do something with it
end
```

Comment: so if I have got a dataset with image names like: `new_tumor1845_2.jpg`, `new_tumor1846_2.jpg`, `new_tumor1847_2.jpg` etc. I should write`pattern = 'new_tumor*_2.jpg`

Comment: yes, exactly! You can even pimp it up to just check for numbers... but most often `'*'` is enough. Check out the [regular expressions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btn_p45_sep_shared-expression) that you can use